# CSS3 transform flickers vertically aligned element

Tags: css, css-transitions, vertical-alignment, css-transforms, flicker

For structural reasons I must use absolute positioning + translateY(-50%) to vertically align elements.

However animating these vertically aligned elements shows a glitch on every browser. Elements blur during and flickering at the end of animations.

I've already tried using perspective, translateZ, rotateZ but no luck..

### EDIT -> problem NOT solved - please check latest reply to know more

You can see the issue in the attached snippet

```css
#wrapper {
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#elem {
  transition: all 500ms ease 0ms;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#wrapper:hover #elem {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.3);  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="elem">Lorem Ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use em positioning technique instead of transform. It seems that transform: translate() wa causing problems with rendering.

```css
#wrapper {
  font-size:15px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}

#elem {
  transition: all 500ms ease 0ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -1em 10% 0;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
}
#wrapper:hover #elem {
 font-size:1.3em
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="elem">Lorem Ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to solve browser glitch in my example. However real-world case is much more complex. I've created a new fiddle using EM and % sizes for all elements: https://jsfiddle.net/979d7635/28/

Comment: Plus, using perspective rule, it becomes totally blurred on scale https://jsfiddle.net/979d7635/29/